# Mark test as ignored based on condition

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I want only some subset of my test methods to run on a production environment. I annotate such test methods with `@ProdAllowed` annotation. I also wrote a small custom JUnit runner, which overrides the runChild method so it runs only for `@ProdAllowed` methods while on "PROD" environment:

```java
public class ProdAwareRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public ProdAwareRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected void runChild(FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
        ProdAllowed annotation = method.getAnnotation(ProdAllowed.class);

        String env = CreditCheckSuite.getEnv().trim();
        if (annotation != null || "DEV".equalsIgnoreCase(env) || "UAT".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {
            super.runChild(method, notifier);
        } else {
            notifier.fireTestIgnored(null); // this probably needs to be changed
        }
    }
}
```

This works quite well, but I want a little more - to have this skipped test methods to be marked in Eclipse as ignored (right now they are marked as not run, which is not exactly what I want)

Comment: A built-in mechanism within junit [is using categories](http://www.hascode.com/2012/12/running-categorized-tests-using-junit-maven-and-annotated-test-suites/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a [rule](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html) by extending [TestWatcher](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html)

```
public class DoNotRunOnProd extends TestWatcher {
  protected void starting(Description description) { {
    ProdAllowed annotation = description.getAnnotation(ProdAllowed.class);
    String env = CreditCheckSuite.getEnv().trim();
    if ((annotation == null) && !"DEV".equalsIgnoreCase(env) && !"UAT".equalsIgnoreCase(env)) {
      throw new AssumptionViolatedException("Must not run on production.")
    }
  }
}
```

and add it to your test

```
public class Test {
  @Rule
  public final TestRule doNotRunOnProd = new DoNotRunOnProd();

  ...
}
```

Comment: It seems that these days rules are replacing runners, no need to write a custom runner here. +1

Comment: My main question is in the last sentence of original post - I would like to have not annotated tests marked as ignored while on PROD. With your approach, Eclipse marks not annotated tests as passed, which is not really what I want to see.

Answer (score 0):

This is already implemented (and actively used) in [TestNG Groups](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups):

```
public class Test1 {
    @Test(groups = { "dev", "uat" })
    public void testMethod1() {
    }

    @Test(groups = {"uat", "prod"} )
    public void testMethod2() {
    }

    @Test(groups = { "prod" })
    public void testMethod3() {
    }
}
```